# Do commercially produced barley matzos exist?

Tags: product-recommendation, passover, matzah, dagan-five-grains

From what I understand, there are commercially produced matzos made from wheat (including spelt) and rye and oats.

For some reason, I cannot find commercially produced barley matzos.

Do they exist?

If so, why are they so difficult to find?

If not, why not?

Comment: Probably the answer to the either of the last two questions is that of lack of demand: If there aren't _enough_ people willing to buy barley matzos (and probably pay extra for the privilege), then there is less reason/incentive to produce them.

Comment: For what it's worth, according to the Hebrew Wikipedia's "[שעורה תרבותית](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA#%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA)", Karaites eat barley matzos on Pesach, as they consider it to be "לחם עוני".

Comment: Why would someone want them? Everything but wheat is bedieved and only for people with wheat allergies https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90391/759